# Song Lyrics - On topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I had found a meta discussion from 2010, but I imagine policy may have changed since then?

I have a couple of questions I would like to ask regarding meter, repetition, general structure, etc. Is (the lyrical part of) songwriting on-topic here?

Comment: Older thread: [Song lyrics and poetry](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/111/26)

Comment: Yes!  And please note that we even have a [tag:lyrics] tag, as well as one for [tag:rhythm], if that is part of your question.

Answer (score 7):

If questions are specifically about lyrics and not music, they're fine. Questions purely about music can be asked on [Music|SE](https://music.stackexchange.com).

However, songs aren't just music and lyrics; there's a lot of interplay between the two. Questions that mention the music but are primarily oriented to the lyrics are, IMO, fine.

Comment: *"Questions that mention the music but are primarily oriented to the lyrics are, IMO, fine."* Yes, if questions about the lyrics are on topic, it should follow that questions about lyrics but which mention the associated music should also be on topic. This would be similar to how questions seeking critique on own writing are off topic, but questions using own writing as examples (e.g. for illustrating a point of difficulty) in otherwise on topic questions are on topic.

Comment: Lyrics are another form of poetry, after all.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about writing song lyrics, yes. If you are asking about someone else's lyrics then the [same rules](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242/are-literature-questions-appropriate-on-writers-se) would apply as to someone else's work. If you are asking "are these lyrics good" or "please write lyrics" then it's off-topic.

Basically, if it would be on-topic if it was a book instead of a song then it's on topic.

Comment: Just to add to this: questions about analysing someone else's lyrics are on-topic at [literature.se] SE, so the same rules apply up to and including "chuck 'em to Literature [quality allowing]".